# Equation of tangent to a curve (Just need help with $\frac{dy}{dx}$)?

Tags: calculus

If $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| < (x_1-x_2)^2\,$ (note the pipes represent the modulus, the absolute value) for all $x_1\,,\,x_2\,\in\Bbb R\,$ , find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=f(x)$ at the point $(1,2)$.

The difficulty: Never understood derivative in inequality form. Any hints?

What I understand: (I'm a visual learner) The absolute change in the function f(x), when x is changed by a value of h is less than $h^2$ (as $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\lt h^2)$ But what to do with this?? I know the equation to the tangent is $(y-2)=(x-1)*\frac{dy}{dx}$. Can we find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the given info:

$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\right|<\frac{|x-1|^2}{|x-1|}=|x-1|$$

Now just remeber that by *mere definition*:

$$f'(1):=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Clear so far, but does this mean that |f'(1)|<h (h tending to 0) ? This is never possible except if f'(1)=0. Am I correct till this part?

Comment: Well, of course. the first part of the proof means the limit in the last part must be zero: just use the squeeze theorem, for example.

Comment: Well, thanks then- this means the line would be y=2

Comment: Indeed so: the derivative is zero at $\,(1,2)\,$